# Integrate share video Facebook with apps swift2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, frameworks, share

I have a little problem,

I want on my app  create a directly redirect link via Facebook to share my video instantly recorded via my app.

I try with Social.framework like : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LPFv.png)

But after clicking on "send", the application said my there was a mistake.

I don't understand why I can't share video, thanks to help me